# Process.Exited never fires

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-5

I created a generic class to execute a console application while redirecting its output to a `RichTextBox` in my form.

The code works just fine, but the `Process.Exited` event never fires even though the console application exists normally after it completes it function.

<s>Also, `WaitForExit` doesn't seem to do anything and any code I write after it is never executed for some reason.</s>

Here's the class (**updated**):

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

public class ConsoleProcess
{
    private string fpath;
    public ConsoleProcess(string filePath)
    {
        fpath = filePath;
    }

    public void Run(string arguments)
    {
        var procInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
        {
            FileName = fpath,
            Arguments = arguments,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
        };

        var proc = new Process() { EnableRaisingEvents = true, StartInfo = procInfo };

        proc.OutputDataReceived += Proc_DataReceived;
        proc.ErrorDataReceived += Proc_DataReceived;
        proc.Exited += Proc_Exited;

        proc.Start();
        proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
        proc.BeginErrorReadLine();
    }

    public event EventHandler<EventArgs>? ProcessExited;
    private void Proc_Exited(object? sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ProcessExited?.Invoke(sender, e);
    }

    public event EventHandler<DataReceivedEventArgs>? DataReceived;
    private void Proc_DataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataReceived?.Invoke(sender, e);
    }
}
```

Here's the code I use in the `Form`:

```
        ConsoleProcess process = new("console_app.exe");
        process.DataReceived += Process_DataReceived;
        process.ProcessExited += Process_Exited;

        private async void Execute()
        {
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                process.Run("--arguments");
            });
        }

        private void Process_DataReceived(object? sender, System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            //do stuff
        }

        private void Process_Exited(object? sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Done");
        }
```

**PS: I'm aware that there are several posts about this issue, and I've checked them, but none of them helped, so here I am.**

Comment: `ConsoleProcess : Process` <-- _Yikes!_ **You should not be subclassing `Process`!**

Comment: Have you used your debugger? If not, **why not**?

Comment: Because your `class ConsoleProcess` inherits from `Process` it has its own `Exited` event, which is a separate instance from your `Process` instance created in your `Run` method.

Comment: ...it sounds like you're new to the whole "composition vs. inheritance" _thing_. The long-and-short of it (thesedays) is generally that _inheritance is not the answer_, *especially* w.r.t. inheriting from (subclassing) standard library types. (To drive this point home even further: Microsoft recently made almost all classes in .NET `sealed` which prevents subclassing - though this is intended for performance reasons rather than stopping people from abusing OOP inheritnace).

Comment: The proc.Exited event is not subscribed.  Get ahead by using `this` instead of `proc`.

Answer (score 1):

To solve the issue that you're facing, try adding `proc.WaitForExit();`.

**Code**:

```
    ...
proc.Start();
proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
proc.BeginErrorReadLine();

//added - wait for exit
proc.WaitForExit(); 
    ...
```

---

If you want to use `Task`, then try the following:

**Note**: I renamed class `ConsoleProcess` to `HelperProcess` as the original name seems somewhat deceptive.

**Create a new project** - Windows Forms App

- Name: `ProcessTest`
- Target Framework: `.NET 5`

**Create a class** (name: HelperProcess.cs)

**HelperProcess**:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ProcessTest
{
    public class HelperProcess
    {
        public event EventHandler<EventArgs> ProcessExited;
        public event EventHandler<DataReceivedEventArgs> DataReceived;

        private string fPath;

        public HelperProcess(string filePath)
        {
            fPath = filePath;
        }

        public async Task Run(string arguments)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"fPath: {fPath}");

            var procInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
            {
                FileName = fPath,
                Arguments = arguments,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
            };

            using (Process proc = new Process() { EnableRaisingEvents = true, StartInfo = procInfo })
            {
                //subscribe to events
                proc.OutputDataReceived += Proc_DataReceived;
                proc.ErrorDataReceived += Proc_DataReceived;
                proc.Exited += Proc_Exited;

                //start
                proc.Start();

                //start reading
                proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
                proc.BeginErrorReadLine();

                //Debug.WriteLine("before proc.WaitForExitAsync");

                //wait for exit
                await proc.WaitForExitAsync();

                //Debug.WriteLine("after proc.WaitForExitAsync");

                //unsubscribe from events
                proc.OutputDataReceived -= Proc_DataReceived;
                proc.ErrorDataReceived -= Proc_DataReceived;
                proc.Exited -= Proc_Exited;
            }
        }

        private void Proc_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Debug.WriteLine("Proc_Exited");
            ProcessExited?.Invoke(sender, e);
        }

        private void Proc_DataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            //ToDo: add desired code

            //Debug.WriteLine($"Proc_DataReceived: {e.Data}");

            //if (DataReceived != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data))
            //{
            //    DataReceived.Invoke(sender, e);
            //}

            DataReceived?.Invoke(sender, e);
        }
    }
}
```

**Add button to Form1** (name: btnRun)

- Double-click button to add `Click` event handler

**Open Properties Window**

- In VS menu, click **View**
- Select **Properties Window**

**Add `FormClosed` event handler to Form1**

- In Properties Window, select **Form1** from the drop-down
- Click [image]
- Double-click **FormClosed** to add the event handler to Form1

**Form1**:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ProcessTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private HelperProcess _process = null;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            string fPath = string.Empty;

            //environment variable windir has the same value as SystemRoot
            //use 'Sysnative' to access 64-bit files (in System32) if program is running as 32-bit process
            //use 'SysWow64' to access 32-bit files on 64-bit OS

            if (Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem && !Environment.Is64BitProcess)
                fPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("windir"), "Sysnative", "wbem", "wmic.exe");
            else
                fPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("windir"), "System32", "wbem", "wmic.exe");

            //create new instance
            _process = new HelperProcess(fPath);

            //subscribe to events
            _process.DataReceived += Process_DataReceived;
            _process.ProcessExited += Process_ProcessExited;
        }

        private async void btnRun_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("before Execute");
            await Execute();
            Debug.WriteLine("after Execute");
        }

        private async Task Execute()
        {
            await _process.Run("process get");

            Debug.WriteLine("after _process.Run");
        }

        private void Process_ProcessExited(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Main: Process_ProcessExited");
        }

        private void Process_DataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"Main: Process_DataReceived: {e.Data}");
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (_process != null)
            {
                //unsubscribe from events
                _process.DataReceived -= Process_DataReceived;
                _process.ProcessExited -= Process_ProcessExited;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Resources**:

- [Process Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?view=net-6.0)
- [Process.Exited Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.exited?view=net-6.0)
- [Process.WaitForExit Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.waitforexit?view=net-6.0)
- [Process.WaitForExitAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.waitforexitasync?view=net-6.0)
- [How to subscribe to and unsubscribe from events (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/how-to-subscribe-to-and-unsubscribe-from-events#:%7E:text=In%20order%20to%20prevent%20resource,encapsulates%20the%20subscriber%27s%20event%20handler.)

Comment: Even though the console app had finished and exited from memory, the `Process.Exited` still didn't fire. But, when I was closing my WinForms app or started another `Run` only then did the event fire.  
Any idea what could be causing this odd behvaiour?

Comment: @root: In the code I posted above I've shown how one can.use `WriteLine` to debug one's code. If one uses`Task`, then one needs to pay attention to where one uses `void` to ensure that the order of execution is as expected.