# In .NET, is there a good way to determine whether a process has terminated?

Tags: c#, .net, process

In .NET, there is the class System.Diagnostics.Process. It has the property HasExited, which should tell me whether the process has terminated. However, the documentation says "When standard output has been redirected to asynchronous event handlers, it is possible that output processing will not have completed when this property returns true. To ensure that asynchronous event handling has been completed, call the WaitForExit() overload that takes no parameter before checking HasExited." (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.hasexited?view=netframework-4.5#system-diagnostics-process-hasexited).

What does "standard output has been redirected to asynchronous event handlers" mean? I don't know this. And, because of this, it seems that this property is not a good way to determine whether a process has terminated. The documentation recommends "call the WaitForExit() overload that takes no parameter before checking HasExited". But that method will wait until the process and event handlers to exit, which is not to simply determine whether the process (and the strange "event handlers") has exited.

So, in .NET, is there a good way to determine whether a process (including those strange "event handlers") has terminated?

Comment: Why do you think this property is not good? Do you really want to determine whether a process has terminated or for other purposes? There is also a WaitForExitAsync method if you prefer asynchronization.

Comment: If you use the *asynchronous* version (event driven), you set `EnableRaisingEvents = true`, which then raises the `Exited` event when the Process exits (in this case, you don't call `WaitForExit()`, of course). Or, if you need to wait asynchronously, do as mentioned in the previous comment, if `WaitForExitAsync()` is available (.NET 5+)

Comment: The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71846819/10024425

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput

Answer (score 0):

Regarding "standard output has been redirected to asynchronous event handlers" I can guess that this is about the case when you use a form of standard output stream redirection which uses an asynchronous event handler in the parent process to process the output of the child process (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.outputdatareceived along with the sample code). You should understand this like even if the HasExited property may return true, your parent process may still be executing output processing code asynchronously. This potentially puts you in danger because you may start doing some work believing the child process and all activities related to it (like Process.OutputDataReceived event handler execution) have already finished, while they (the activities) may have not.

So, unless you're doing this fancy async output processing, using the HasExited property should be reliable approach. Otherwise, you could do something like this to be able to periodically check for "real" process exiting (instead of waiting/awaiting):

```cs
Process process = Process.Start("notepad.exe");

bool processExited = false;

_ = Task.Run(async () =>
{
    await process.WaitForExitAsync();
    Volatile.Write(ref processExited, true);
});

while (!Volatile.Read(ref processExited))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Not exited");
    // Do you're stuff while it's still running.
    await Task.Delay(1000);
}

Console.WriteLine("Exited!");
```