Python script run from C# hangs at high memory usage
I want my C# (.NET 8) app to start a Python script under Python 3.12. The Python script is fairly resource-intensive. When I run the script manually, all is well; it consumes memory up to a bit over 3 GB RAM, then completes. But when I run it in C# by spawning a new CMD window, it consumes just about 1 GB of memory and then the process CPU drops to 0% and it hangs indefinitely.
This is the code I'm using to first activate the virtual environment, then run the script and capture its output.
        var process = new Process
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = "cmd",
                Arguments = "",
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardInput = true,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                WorkingDirectory = workingDirectory
            }
        };
        process.StartInfo.EnvironmentVariables.Add("TRANSFORMERS_CACHE", _transformersCacheDirectory);
        process.Start();

        using var sw = process.StandardInput;
        if (sw.BaseStream.CanWrite)
        {
            sw.WriteLine(".\\venv\\scripts\\activate");
            sw.WriteLine($"python test.py");
            sw.Flush();
            sw.Close();
        }

        result = await process.StandardOutput.ReadToEndAsync();
        await process.WaitForExitAsync();

        var error = await process.StandardError.ReadToEndAsync();


Try using a using statement instead of a using declaration. Also, seldom is it necessary to use cmd.exe.

The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71846819/10024425 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/78380519/10024425
